# Uploading CSV or XML for edit and return

Tags: php, mysql, xml, csv

I haven't done much coding in the way of HTML5 and PHP before as ive always used Python and only created in system applications instead of web based apps.

Ive tried to find but could not, any information that might assist me with my latest task.

I would like for users to be able to upload a CSV or XML file (Havent decided on format yet) that contains SKUs in one field and Prices in another (Columns).

I then want the user to be able to specify a set of variables and have the document edited to that effect.

Im not sure if I would have to use MySQL to achieve this, and I have no experience with it so if I can at all avoid it then that would be preferable.

Any advice / suggestions on material for doing this, or even actual examples of how this might be achieved would go a long way to increasing my understanding of how to approach this task.

Kind Regards.
Lewis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) method and [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) methods to manipulate a csv file in php.
For xml files you can use [simpleXML parser](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_read.asp)

I will give an example for CSV files in php.

*Reading a CSV file*

```
if(file_exists("/tmp/my_file.csv")){
    $filex = fopen("/tmp/my_file.csv","r");
}
else{
    echo "file not found";
}
$data = array();
while(!feof($file))
{
  $data[] = fgetcsv($file);
}
fclose($filex);
//now you can manipulate $data as you wish
```

*Writing to CSV file*

```
$list = array
(
"abcd,efgh,ijkl,mnop",
"qrst,uvwx,yzab,cdef"
);

$file = fopen("my_file.csv","w");

foreach ($list as $line)
  {
  fputcsv($file,explode(',',$line));
  }

fclose($file);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the input, i didnt realise it was that simple for php to have input into a csv file.

Is there anywhere I can find a list of commands that manipulate existing fields within the CSV?

Is there any way to ensure that certain fields meet required criteria before executing a script?

Comment: Unfortunately if you want to manipulate existing values of the csv using php, you have to read the .csv file and change the values using php, then write back to the .csv file with new values. No direct commands to do that.

Comment: So you use =array to list the current existing values in the csv? and then manipulate and then write back to the csv the new array?

Comment: Thanks for your help, its greatly appreciated.